# Future cancellation in java based on names or an ID

Tags: java, concurrent.futures

I am scheduling a future for execution while adding an item in a cart.Now I want to cancel all the previous instances of Future callbacks which were scheduled when an item is updated in the cart.

I have scheduled my future like for a single item add in the cart like this-

```
 ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

AbandonedCartWorker abw=new AbandonedCartWorker(dao,config,sender,message,receiver_gcm,RETRIES,cart);

ScheduledFuture<String> future=executor.schedule(abw, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now i want to cancel all the previous future callables how can I do this?

Comment: Do you have references to said futures?

Comment: No I do not have the past references,I was thinking to give each instance an ID or name but currently I am not able to do so.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't maintain these references?

Comment: I have searched a lot but I am not able to find how to give callable a name like we can name a thread but I am not able to find.I want to cancel the future callable based on names.Can you please help?

Comment: Could using a `Map` help?

Comment: Yes I though of that but each time I add an item to my cart this method is called so it will create a new instance of the Map,if I am thinking correctly.So the previously saved values in the map would not be retained.

Comment: No.  Keep one instance of the map at an instance level to which you keep adding things.

Comment: Okay,let me try.Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much,yes it did it.I think I had a brain freeze but now works like a charm.